# Executing multiline sed in php: escaping issues

Tags: php, regex, parsing, sed

I am trying to run sed to do a multiline search and replace with the following string

```
$test = "sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/iname=\"".$name.".*item>/".trim(xml)."/g;p;}' ".$file;
exec($test,$cmdresult);
```

sed is choice since the string to be searched is over 10 mb.

During execution compiler issues a warning

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: you may find that `<<<HEREDOC` syntax ends up being more human readable. http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` in `${}`.

```
$test = "sed -n '1h;1!H;\${;g;s/iname=\"".$name.".*item>/".trim(xml)."/g;p;}' ".$file;
exec($test,$cmdresult);
```

In order to let humans read your code, though, you should really split the string up. Create it by concatenating other strings, `sprintf` or HEREDOC.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `$` sign inside the `$test` variable makes PHP think that there is another variable that should be expanded.

Try escaping the `$` character (`\$`), and have a look at the [relevant PHP strings doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).