# Sed non greedy match: matching first xml nodes

Tags: regex, sed, non-greedy

Follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007752/executing-multiline-sed-in-php-escaping-issues)

```
$test = "sed -n '1h;1!H;\${;g;s/<item=\"".$name.".*</\item>/".trim(xml)."/g;p;}' ".$file;
exec($test,$cmdresult);
```

This command executes to find all xml nodes with the specified name passed it as a variable. The only problem here is that the match goes beyond the initial `</item>` to the next nodes, finally to the last `</item>`.

How do I make this non greedy?

Comment: Have you tried to play with sed in a shell (and not by calling it from PHP)? You obviously have some errors here, like `</\item>` instead of `<\/item>`. Sed would inform you about that.

Comment: I know you said you have a large file to process, but you should really use a PHP XML library.

Comment: @Dennis simplexml in php does not allow me to replace nodes

Comment: Surely [one of these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) will.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes its better to use negative class than non greedy match. It allows finer control and is a bit more efficient. I.E. to match everything but not tag close you can do [^>]*. Though if you can have strings that can have ">" in them this will not work. You can read about this a bit more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html